# BackgroundWorker's ProgressChanged not updating UI until end of work loop

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I am coding a WPF application that will grab email's off of an IMAP account, and then export them into a user-selected folder.

I use a BackgroundWorker to download the emails. However, my UI isn't being updated until the loop is over.

Any tips would be appreciated.

```
Class MainWindow
    Public MailRepo As MailRepository
    Private bw_Connect As New BackgroundWorker
    Private bw_Save As New BackgroundWorker

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        bw_Connect.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        bw_Connect.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        AddHandler bw_Connect.DoWork, AddressOf bw_Connect_DoWork

        bw_Save.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        bw_Save.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        AddHandler bw_Save.DoWork, AddressOf bw_Save_DoWork
        AddHandler bw_Save.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bw_Save_ProgressChanged

    End Sub
```

```
    Private Sub bw_Save_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)

        If bw_Connect.CancellationPending = True Then
            e.Cancel = True
        Else
            SaveEmails()
        End If
    End Sub
```

```
Private Sub SaveEmails()
    Dim allMails As IEnumerable(Of Message)
    'Get All Emails in Mailbox
    Try
        Dim mailBox As String
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DirectCast(Sub()
                                         mailBox = comboBoxEmailFolders.SelectedValue
                                     End Sub, Action))
        allMails = MailRepo.GetAllMails(mailBox)
    Catch i4e As Imap4Exception
        MsgBox("Error: Folder not found" & vbCrLf & i4e.Message)
        Return
    End Try
    Dim msg As Message
    Dim msgInt As Integer = 1
    'Save each message
    For Each msg In allMails
        bw_Save.ReportProgress(100 / allMails.Count * msgInt, Nothing)
        SaveMessage(msg)
        msgInt += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub bw_Save_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
        Dim percentDone As String = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() & "%"
        updateStatus("Saving Emails " & percentDone & " done.")
        progressBarStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    End Sub
```

Comment: What do you do in `bw_Save_ProgressChanged`?

Comment: On a side note, you can make the code more straightforward by using [the `Handles` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y.aspx).

Comment: what values can allMails.Count have? (If it's > 100, then BAD!)

Comment: codersl: It can be as many as the user has emails in a folder. Why would being > 100 be bad?

Comment: GSerg: I will update with the bw_Save_ProgressChanged code

updateStatus() simply updates a textBox with the string passed in.
I also update a progressBar

Comment: How does it look like - the progress bar does not change? Can you drag the window around while it's working? Also I'm not sure if `Dispatcher.Invoke`is bad or not in this case, but can you pass the `comboBoxEmailFolders.SelectedValue` to the worker [as an argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f00zz5b2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead?

Comment: Being > 100 is bad because 100/101 = 0

Comment: @codersl That is only true when integer division is used. In VB, unlike C#, there is a separate operator for integer division, ``\``. The usual division operator, `/`, will divide numbers mathematically regardless of their type.

Comment: @GSerg Wow, you're right! Did not know that.